# Swift override function in extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics

If I have a class:

```
class Spaceship<FuelType> {
    function prepareForLiftoff() throws {
        //Start the countdown!
    }
}
```

I originally assumed that I would be able to override `prepareForLiftoff` without subclassing by adding an extension:

```
extension Spaceship where FuelType: CollectionType {
    func prepareForLiftoff() throws {}
}
```

This code doesn't compile though, the error says `invalid redeclaration` of the function, which makes sense.

**My question is:** Is there anyway to override a function of a particular class? In other words can I replace the functionality under certain conditions like the example above where `FuelType: CollectionType`. If not, is there any other workaround or way to achieve that behavior (maybe declaring another protocol, idk)

Now that I think about it more, I would have to say that's not possible because what's to stop someone from overriding any of the standard library functions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html):

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

The documentation lists carefully and precisely what an extension is allowed to do.

As to your question:

> Is there anyway to override a function of a particular class

Yes, it's called subclassing.

Comment: Fair enough, I had my fingers crossed.

Comment: How would one override a function of a `struct`?

Comment: @matt: Do you have an idea why overriding in an extension in a *different framework* is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123963/redeclaring-members-in-an-extension-hides-the-original-member-sometimes-why  ?

Comment: @MartinR https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3228 and https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2935

Comment: @matt: Thanks! – (I wonder a bit why SR-3228 is closed as a duplicate of SR-2935, the latter seems to be specific about overriding Objective-C methods, but that is not important to me at present.)

Comment: You can override a function of a parent class in an extension. The question is if you should.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overriding, you may like to try swizzling. For example the following code allows you to run your own `viewWillAppear`. `Swift 3`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override class func initialize() {
        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        guard self === UIViewController.self else { return }
        DispatchQueue.once(token: "viewWillAppear") {
            let originalSelector = #selector(self.viewWillAppear(_:))
            let swizzledSelector = #selector(self.proj_viewWillAppear1(animated:))
            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }

    func proj_viewWillAppear1(animated: Bool) {
        self.proj_viewWillAppear1(animated: animated)
        let viewControllerName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
        print("viewWillAppear: \(viewControllerName)")
    }
}
```

Update 20170621

```
public extension DispatchQueue {
    private static var _onceTracker = [String]()

    public class func once(file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, block:(Void)->Void) {
        let token = file + ":" + function + ":" + String(line)
        once(token: token, block: block)
    }

    public class func once(token: String, block:(Void)->Void) {
        objc_sync_enter(self)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }

        if _onceTracker.contains(token) {
            return
        }

        _onceTracker.append(token)
        block()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can i make this work now? there is no DispatchQueue.once. thanks

Comment: @ilan sure you can create an extension like the one I added, or come up with your own version of implementation.

Comment: You shouldn't swizzle generally speaking

Comment: I'm with @barndog. Swizzling should be avoided at all costs.There's a better than even chance Apple will not allow swizzled apps in the App Store starting with iOS 14.

Comment: I totally agree with you guys, but I was just providing a solution to address the specific technical question from OP. Generally speaking, even subclassing should not be used widely as composition is always above inheritance. But IMO stackoverflow is not the place that you just throw SOLID principles and protocol oriented programming onto others face and let them learn how to code properly; a question was asked, and a solution has been given, and that's it.