# Declaration is only valid at file scope (extension)

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

i try to make my app just in portrait mode iam using navigationcontroller
i get this error iam usring `Xcode7` and `Swift 2` And Target System `IOS 9.3`
Declaration is only valid at file scope

```
        extension UINavigationController {
            public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
                return visibleViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
            }
            public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
                return visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate()
            }
        }

        extension UITabBarController {
            public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
                if let selected = selectedViewController {
                    return selected.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
                }
                return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
            }
            public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
                if let selected = selectedViewController {
                    return selected.shouldAutorotate()
                }
                return super.shouldAutorotate()
            }
        }
```

Thnx

Answer (score 14):

The error message is quite clear. You cannot declare an `extension` inside of anything - inside a `class` declaration, inside a `struct` declaration, etc. It must be outside of everything, at the top level of the containing file. There must be no curly braces around it.

You have not shown the context in which you are declaring this `extension`, but clearly there *are* curly braces around it, or you wouldn't be getting the error!

But in any case, no matter where you declare them, *your* extensions are illegal: you can't do an `override` in an extension. (See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33862519/341994).)

Comment: @kvra13 - move your extensions to the "top of the file".