# Can I override a Swift method that has been overridden by an extension?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create an extension for debugging a class to print some output when you enter certain methods. I want to be able to reuse this code in many different classes, and I want to keep those classes clean from this debugging code while also not repeating code (keeping DRY). That's why I thought of using an extension like this:

```
class A: ... {
    override func myMethod() { 
        super.myMethod()
        print("hello A")
    }
}

extension A {
    override func myMethod() { 
        print("hello extension")
    }
}
```

And I would like that when `myMethod()` is called, to see this

```
hello extension
hello A
```

(or the other way around, I don't care)

But the problem is that the compiler is saying `"myMethod() has already been overridden here"`

Any ideas?

Comment: The body of a class and an extension can't both provide overrides. How would the compiler decide which to pick?

Comment: well, maybe the extension could call `self.myMethod()` instead of `super.myMethod()` or something like that. Or that super for extensions meant the class ... whatever. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You really need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862414/swift-override-function-in-extension or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions

Comment: You should also provide the way in which you are going to reuse it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot
> override existing functionality.

Answer is here [Swift override function in extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862414/swift-override-function-in-extension)